# What is the caster level for a supernatural ability?

Tags: magic, dnd-3e

As per [the errata to the D&D 3.0 DMG, as explained here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/69886/16044), supernatural abilities can be dispelled as if they were spells.  However, I have never seen a definition of what their caster level is, and you need to know that in order to roll the dispel check.  So, is this a case of handbook dysfunction (the DMG says its possible, but neither the PHB nor the MM defines the caster level needed), or is there a definition somewhere I'm missing?

Answer (score 8):

Caster level is usually equal to HD, except where explicitly noted otherwise.

From the “Special Abilities, Supernatural” glossary entry, page 315 of the *Monster Manual*:

> Unless otherwise noted, a supernatural ability has an effective caster level equal to the creature's Hit Dice.

Comment: Is this true for PC supernatural abilities as well? (Such as a Druid's Wild Shape)

Comment: @Shalvenay Could you please ask that as a separate question, and link to or reference this one?

Comment: I don't believe it is defined elsewhere, and since often caster level = HD = level would be a sensible result, I don't think there's a reason to doubt it.