# What caster level is used for PC supernatural abilities?

Tags: magic, dnd-3e

As per [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/69886/16044), D&D 3.0 lets you  use *dispel magic* to remove supernatural abilities from targets.  Typically, this is something PCs do to monsters, so, the applicable caster level is defined in the MM in terms of the creature's HD, as stated [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/69888/16044).  However, PCs can get supernatural abilities as well, typically from their class (such as a druid's Wild Shape), and of course, some monsters do cast *dispel magic*.  What caster level is used for PC supernatural abilities, and does it depend on what mix of class levels the character has for a given amount of Hit Dice?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Unless otherwise noted, a supernatural ability has an effectivecaster level equal to the creature’s Hit Dice. The saving throw (if any) against a supernatural ability is 10 + 1/2 the creature’s HD + the creature’s ability modifier (usually Charisma)."

[Source](http://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/SRD:Special_Abilities_Overview)

It really just functions off of your hit die. What classes you have is largely irrelevant except for the hit die and maybe the ability mod that goes with it. I would just use the same formula for pc's as for monsters to keep things simple.

Comment: You should make sure to format this properly using blockquotes so it's clear which part is quoted; you should also add a link or some other attribution.

Comment: Oh ok. I'm new to the site so I'll look into the formatting and such. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Welcome to the site, Ilyando :)